# Doxygen problems with paths in \file command

Tags: c, doxygen

I've got the following problem using Doxygen 1.7.x: I document various files in a subdirectory and they are referred with different filename styles, both with and without their path, on the corresponding `Modules` page. But I want to have relative paths (w.r.t. the project root) on the modules page.

The two files are tagged as follows:

```
/**
 * @addtogroup examples_itsolver
 * @{ 
 * @file example/itsolver/bicgstab_1.c 
 * @brief Demostrate the usage of BiCGStab 
 * @date 05/21/2012 
 * @version $Id$
 *@}
 */
```

and

```
/**
 * @addtogroup examples_itsolver
 * @{ 
 * @file example/itsolver/sor.c 
 * @brief Demostrate the usage of SOR
 * @date 05/21/2012 
 * @version $Id$
 *@}
 */
```

This results in

```
file    bicgstab_1.c
        Demonsrate the usage of BiCGStab.

file    example/itsolver/sor.c
        Demonstrate the usage of the SOR Iterative Solver.
```

on the `Module overview` page. But I want to have all files documented like `sor.c` across the whole project. How can I achieve this? Using the `FULL_PATH_NAMES` configuration option does not help.

A full example (including the generated html output) is available on http://www-e.uni-magdeburg.de/makoehle/doxygen_error.tgz

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this with the info you provided. If you have a self-contained example (source+config file in a zip) demonstrating the problem then please file a bug report in the doxygen bug tracker and attach the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your example there are two files called sor.c

```
example/itsolver/sor.c
lib/itsolver/sor.c
```

doxygen will prepend as much of the path as needed to make the name unique.

If example contains usage examples, then it is better not to include these in the input, but use @snippet, @include, or @example instead and point `EXAMPLE_PATH` to your example directory.